# How to highlight a point in line graph by drawing a circle around it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates, axis, nodes-near-coords

I want to highlight a point (i.e., `(3, 4.8)`) in the following line graph by drawing a red circle around it. However, as you can see, the circle is not drawn at the expected position.

Why? And how to fix this?

[image: score-mark]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
    ymin = 4.5, ymax = 5,
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick = {},
    ymajorgrids = true,
    grid style = dashed,
]
\addplot[color = blue, mark = square, nodes near coords, ]
    coordinates {
      (1, 5.0)
      (2, 4.90)
      (3, 4.80)
      (4, 4.70)
      (5, 4.60)
    };
  % first try: failed
  \node (mark) [draw, red, circle, minimum size = 5pt] at (3, 4.80) {(1)};
\end{axis}
% second try: failed
\node (mark) [draw, red, circle, minimum size = 5pt] at (3, 4.80) {(2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you specify `axis cs:`

[image]

As Schrödinger's cat mentioned, `axis cs:` became the default in pgfplots `1.11`, but as this change was not backward compatible, to activate this requires one to explicitly specify the compatibility mode to some version greater than `1.11`.  The latest version is accessed by specifying

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
```

To access the newest version, one could specify `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`. However, use of this option is discouraged as a future compile may not behave as desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
    ymin = 4.5, ymax = 5,
    xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick = {},
    ymajorgrids = true,
    grid style = dashed,
]
\addplot[color = blue, mark = square, nodes near coords, ]
    coordinates {
      (1, 5.0)
      (2, 4.90)
      (3, 4.80)
      (4, 4.70)
      (5, 4.60)
    };
  % first try: now works
  \node (mark) [draw, red, circle, minimum size = 5pt, inner sep=2pt, thick] 
      at (axis cs: 3, 4.80) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Good point. Have included that in the text now.